# "min() arg is an empty sequence"

Tags: python

I created a function that consumes a list of values and produces the average. However it only works when I use integer values. I get the following error when I make the values into floats:

> min() arg is an empty sequence

What's wrong here. If it works for integers, why not floats. How do I fix this?

Comment: maybe, you will provide some code :)

Comment: Can you edit your question and put your code in here.

Comment: ...not just "your code", but "code that you tested, when run on its own in an otherwise-blank interpreter, to produce the error in question". Which shouldn't be hard -- for this error, I'd expect it to be just one line.

Answer (score 4):

As the error suggests, you passing in an empty sequence to you `min` call. What that means is if for example you have an `elem_list` and are calling `min(elem_list)`, the list is currently empty `[]` and is erroring. Whatever your calling `min` on is currently empty.